# Git/Github: Manage a forked repository with public and private submodules

Tags: git, github, saleor

I have a forked repository that has three submodules, all of them are public but I want to change one of them for my own private repository. I clone the repository and after that I execute `git submodule update --init`, git get the public ones, but with the private one git prompts a credential window that avoids downloading.

### .submodule file

```sh
[submodule "saleor"]
    path = saleor
    url = https://github.com/mirumee/saleor.git
[submodule "saleor-storefront"] -> I want to replace this one with my private repo
    path = saleor-storefront
    url = https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-storefront.git
[submodule "saleor-dashboard"]
    path = saleor-dashboard
    url = https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-dashboard.git
```

---

### Update 1

With the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65801385/8582246) sugested by VonC, a new error occurred, the replaced submodule cannot be downloaded. How to reproduce this error:

1. I fork [saleor-platform repository](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-platform).
2. I clone on my machine the forked repository created on step 1:

```sh
D:\git\tests\saleor-platform>git clone https://github.com/<organization>/saleor-platform
```

3. Create a new repository to replace `saleor-storefront`, `saleor-storefront` is a submodule in `saleor-platform` the repository forked on step 1.
4. Replace the submodule as VonC user suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65801521/8582246), It should be noted that I want to change the `saleor-storefront` submodule for a private repo inside an `organization`, and it is a totally new implementation i.e. it only has the initial commit:

```sh
D:\git\tests\saleor-platform>git submodule set-url -- saleor-storefront https://github.com/<organization>/my-new-brand-implementation
```

5. from the parent repository(`saleor-platform`) check new changes with `git status`, add new changes `git add .`, commit the changes `git commit -m "Update saleor-storefront submodule"`:

```sh
D:\git\tests\saleor-platform>git st
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   .gitmodules

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

D:\git\tests\saleor-platform>git add .

D:\git\tests\saleor-platform>git commit -m "Update saleor-storefront submodule"
[master 53b60e5] Update saleor-storefront submodule
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

6. Push back to my fork:

```sh
D:\git\tests\saleor-platform>git push
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 353 bytes | 353.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
To github.com:<organization>/saleor-platform.git
   cbc31e4..53b60e5  master -> master
```

7. Finally I clone again my repository:

```sh
D:\git\tests\> git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/<organization>/saleor-platform saleor-platform2
Cloning into 'saleor-platform2'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 9, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Receiving objects:  67% (138/205)), reused 3 (delta 0), pack-reused 196
Receiving objects: 100% (205/205), 68.41 KiB | 463.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (99/99), done.
Submodule 'saleor' (https://github.com/mirumee/saleor.git) registered for path 'saleor'
Submodule 'saleor-dashboard' (https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-dashboard.git) registered for path 'saleor-dashboard'
Submodule 'saleor-storefront' (https://github.com/<organization>/my-new-brand-implementation) registered for path 'saleor-storefront'
Cloning into 'D:/git/tests/saleor-platform2/saleor'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 178730, done.
remote: Total 178730 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 178730
Receiving objects: 100% (178730/178730), 100.26 MiB | 2.60 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (130671/130671), done.
Cloning into 'D:/git/tests/saleor-platform2/saleor-dashboard'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 168, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (168/168), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (132/132), done.
remote: Total 38062 (delta 69), reused 71 (delta 32), pack-reused 37894
Receiving objects: 100% (38062/38062), 24.61 MiB | 1.93 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (25652/25652), done.
Cloning into 'D:/git/tests/saleor-platform2/saleor-storefront'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 113, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (113/113), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (98/98), done.
remote: Total 113 (delta 2), reused 113 (delta 2), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (113/113), 300.56 KiB | 523.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), done.
Submodule path 'saleor': checked out '3b31391b92b184b591ef4e85ff6a59cd52cdad98'
Submodule path 'saleor-dashboard': checked out '8bcb8b70878078b74133aea0244dc840d75b492f'
fatal: remote error: upload-pack: not our ref 3ba4ffa8a14f90398462b84e5da088baeb84dfc6
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Fetched in submodule path 'saleor-storefront', but it did not contain 3ba4ffa8a14f90398462b84e5da088baeb84dfc6. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `git config credential.helper` is set (for instance, to `manager-core` on Windows), the credential Windows should [cache your GitHub credentials](https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git) (GitHub user account/password)

Try first:

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/<me>/saleor-storefront.git
```

(replace `<me>` by your GitHub user account, assuming you have forked `saleor-storefront`)

Once you have cached your credentials, and `git ls-remote` does not ask for those anymore, try again to change the submodule URL.

Make sure to change the URL with `git submodule set-url`, as I suggested in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65796573/6309).

An error message like `the remote end hung up unexpectedly Fetched in submodule path 'saleor-storefront', but it did not contain xxx` is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61163331/6309).

You need for the parent repository (your fork) to add and commit the new remote submodule repository tree SHA1, which should be done through `git submodule set-url`, and then push that updated fork.

---

Test: I have forked, then clone saleor-platform.

```sh
D:\git\tests\saleor-platform>git submodule update --init
Submodule 'saleor' (https://github.com/mirumee/saleor.git) registered for path 'saleor'
Submodule 'saleor-dashboard' (https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-dashboard.git) registered for path 'saleor-dashboard'
Submodule 'saleor-storefront' (https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-storefront.git) registered for path 'saleor-storefront'
Cloning into 'D:/git/tests/saleor-platform/saleor'...
Cloning into 'D:/git/tests/saleor-platform/saleor-dashboard'...
Cloning into 'D:/git/tests/saleor-platform/saleor-storefront'...
Submodule path 'saleor': checked out '3b31391b92b184b591ef4e85ff6a59cd52cdad98'
Submodule path 'saleor-dashboard': checked out '8bcb8b70878078b74133aea0244dc840d75b492f'
Submodule path 'saleor-storefront': checked out '3ba4ffa8a14f90398462b84e5da088baeb84dfc6'
```

Then I forked `saleor-storefront`.
I replace that submodule by my own forked submodule:

```
D:\git\tests\saleor-platform>git submodule set-url -- saleor-storefront https://github.com/VonC/saleor-storefront
Synchronizing submodule url for 'saleor-storefront'
```

Update the changed .gitmodules:

```sh
D:\git\tests\saleor-platform>git st
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   .gitmodules

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

D:\git\tests\saleor-platform>git add .

D:\git\tests\saleor-platform>git commit -m "Update saleor-storefront submodule"
[master d9f1f79] Update saleor-storefront submodule
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Push back to my fork

```sh
D:\git\tests\saleor-platform>git push
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 337 bytes | 337.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
To https://github.com/VonC/saleor-platform
   cbc31e4..d9f1f79  master -> master
```

Clone again the main repo (my fork) with my forked submodule:

```sh
D:\git\tests\> git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/VonC/saleor-platform saleor-platform2
Cloning into 'saleor-platform2'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 9, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Receiving objects:  67% (138/205) 205 (delta 3), reused 3 (delta 0), pack-reused 19666% (136/205)
Receiving objects: 100% (205/205), 68.40 KiB | 454.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (99/99), done.
Submodule 'saleor' (https://github.com/mirumee/saleor.git) registered for path 'saleor'
Submodule 'saleor-dashboard' (https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-dashboard.git) registered for path 'saleor-dashboard'
Submodule 'saleor-storefront' (https://github.com/VonC/saleor-storefront) registered for path 'saleor-storefront'
Cloning into 'D:/git/tests/saleor-platform2/saleor'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 237, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (237/237), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (188/188), done.
remote: Total 178889 (delta 93), reused 78 (delta 49), pack-reused 178652
Receiving objects: 100% (178889/178889), 100.57 MiB | 9.63 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (130714/130714), done.
Cloning into 'D:/git/tests/saleor-platform2/saleor-dashboard'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 12, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (12/12), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
remote: Total 37906 (delta 1), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 37894
Receiving objects: 100% (37906/37906), 23.81 MiB | 12.03 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (25584/25584), done.
Cloning into 'D:/git/tests/saleor-platform2/saleor-storefront'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 46, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (46/46), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (37/37), done.
remote: Total 34033 (delta 21), reused 15 (delta 8), pack-reused 33987
Receiving objects: 100% (34033/34033), 17.14 MiB | 3.04 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (23073/23073), done.
Submodule path 'saleor': checked out '3b31391b92b184b591ef4e85ff6a59cd52cdad98'
Submodule path 'saleor-dashboard': checked out '8bcb8b70878078b74133aea0244dc840d75b492f'
Submodule path 'saleor-storefront': checked out '3ba4ffa8a14f90398462b84e5da088baeb84dfc6'
```

Comment: There is a new error: `fatal: remote error: upload-pack: not our ref 3ba4ffa8a14f90398462b84e5da088baeb84dfc6` `fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly` `Fetched in submodule path 'saleor-storefront', but it did not contain 3ba4ffa8a14f90398462b84e5da088baeb84dfc6. Direct fetching of that commit failed.`

Comment: @CristianFlórez I have updated the answer to address your comment.

Comment: My procces is: **1**. Clone my forked repository.  **2**. update my submodule to the new one with `git submodule set-url -- saleor-storefront https://github.com/<my>/saleor-storefront`. **3**. add, commit and push from my parent repository. but the problem persist. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if I'm missing any step. The `SHA1` that its miss comes from the forked repo `saleor-storefront @ 3ba4ffa` so if I update the submodule with my implementation, git doesn't found it any more.

Comment: @CristianFlórez Can you check where that commit comes from? (3ba4ffa8a14f90398462b84e5da088baeb84dfc6)? Is it from saleor-storefront? From onather submodule? From the parent repo?

Comment: @CristianFlórez when you dod git submodule add (your fork), does your fork included that commit? (I suppose not, since we have this error message). If not, why the fork was not updated fith woth the mast most recent original repo content, before being used as submodule replacement?

Comment: This commit comes from `saleor-storefront` submodule that is in the parent forked repository, It was the last commit made in it. You can check the structure of the project that I forked [here](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-platform), If you fork the repository, you clone that fork, replace the `saleor-storefront` submodule with a private own implementation, can reproduce the error.

Comment: @CristianFlórez Sorry, I am on multiple topics at the moment. I will try and reproduce the error.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `git submodule add`. As I told you in previous comments, my process for reproducing this error is as follows: **1**. I fork [saleor-platform repository](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-platform), **2**. I clone on my machine that forked repository, 3. replace the submodule as you suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65801521/8582246), **4**. from the parent repository I do `add, commit and push`, 5. Execute `git submodule update --init --recursive`.

Comment: @CristianFlórez Again, that was a mix-up with another question. I understand this is about the `git submodule set-url`, not add. But I am at work at the moment, so I will have to check that later.

Comment: @CristianFlórez Can you check my sequence of command I have added to the answer? I did not reproduce your error message.

Comment: I do the same steps and obtain the same error, everything goes fine until I run `git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/<me>/saleor-platform saleor-platform2`. When you run `git submodule set-url -- saleor-storefront https://github.com/<me>/saleor-storefront`, what is `saleor-storefront` for you? what do you implement there? remember that I change this module for a private repo not a public fork of `saleor-storefront`. I assume the problem is in my `saleor-storefront` repository, this repository is inside an `organization`, is private and it is a totally new brand implementation.

Comment: I read this in your updated answer... `"I replace that submodule by my own forked submodule:"` I don't fork `saleor-storefront` or any other repository, I create a new repository to replace it, i.e. it has only one initial commit, that's why I don't understand where this comes from in your shell in the last step `Submodule path 'saleor-storefront': checked out '3ba4ffa8a14f90398462b84e5da088baeb84dfc6'` if this commit not exist on my new repository. I update the question with the necesary steps to reproduce the error. please review them and check the errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227669/discussion-between-cristian-florez-and-vonc).