# When I clone a submodule repo I see my branch. But when I clone the parent repo and try to change to a branch in my submodule it gives an error

Tags: git, git-submodules

`git clone sub-mod.git`

`git branch -a`

*develop

mybranch  #branch exists

`git clone --recurse-submodules --branch develop main-project.git`

`cd path/to/sub-mod`

`git branch -a`

*develop #mybranch not listed so cannot change to that. git pull/fetch did not help

Note: I have added the submodule branch name in .gitmodules

Comment: Does the develop branch in the main project have the correct submodules defined? I.e. does path/to/sub-mod actually contain the submodule?

Comment: Yup it contains the submodule. It gives an error saying that particular commit is not found and defaults to develop

Comment: And `git remote show origin` gives the submodule's URL, not that of the main project?

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Yes it gives the submodule url. Error is "fatal: git upload-pack: not our ref ***  Fetched in submodule path /path/to/sub-mod but it did not contain ***

Comment: Have you looked for that error message? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61163082/why-does-git-submodule-update-fail-with-fatal-remote-error-upload-pack-not-o